# Comparing dates giving incorrect outputs

Tags: php, date, date-comparison

I'm creating a function to check which date, in a database table full of date's, is smaller then then current date. As in the past.

I've got 3 date's to test the function with, and the outputs behind them:

Date from last month: **28-04-2015 16:32:00**
Date yet to come: **11-06-2015 13:12:00**
Date from last week: **04-05-2015 09:45:00**

```
$dateNow = date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); //Current
$deadlineDate = "28-04-2015 16:33:18";

if($deadlineDate < $dateNow){ //If date from last month is smaller then the current date
    echo '<tr class="overdue">'; //Overdue class gives that tr an red background color to mark it
    echo '<td>'.$deadlineDate.' is smaller then '.$dateNow.'</td>';
}else{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$deadlineDate.' is bigger dan '.$dateNow.'</td>';
}

</tr>
```

Outputs:

**28-04-2015 16:32:00** *Returns bigger*
**11-06-2015 13:12:00** *Returns smaller*
**04-05-2015 09:45:00** *Returns smaller*

Can anybody tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: you'll probably have to clarify your question along with adding a few examples of things you tried and any debugging output you have in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your "dates" are really strings. And when comparing them it is alphabetical. You need to convert those dates to *real* dates for this to work:

```
$dateNow = new DateTime();
$deadlineDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y H:i:s", "28-04-2015 16:33:18");
if($deadlineDate < $dateNow){ //If date from last month is smaller then the current date
    echo '<tr class="overdue">'; //Overdue class gives that tr an red background color to mark it
    echo '<td>'.$deadlineDate.' is smaller then '.$dateNow.'</td>';
}else{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$deadlineDate.' is bigger dan '.$dateNow.'</td>';
}
```

Converting them into YYYY-MM-DD format will also work.

Comment: I figured it was something like that. I tried to conver them myself but still got the same results. Thanks for the tip, I won't make the same mistake next time :)

Answer (score 2):

You cant compare `date string` like that. Convert it to `timestamp` first.  Use `strtotime`.

```
$dateNow = date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); //Current
$deadlineDate = "28-04-2015 16:33:18";

if(strtotime($deadlineDate) < strtotime($dateNow)){ //If date from last month is smaller then the current date
    echo '<tr class="overdue">'; //Overdue class gives that tr an red background color to mark it
    echo '<td>'.$deadlineDate.' is smaller then '.$dateNow.'</td>';
}else{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$deadlineDate.' is bigger dan '.$dateNow.'</td>';
}
```

Comment: I just tried that a few minutes ago but that didn't work. I used strtotime above the if-else statements. But it seems to be working now. Thanks for the quick answer :)

Comment: The have to use `DateTime` class for this.

Comment: @sgtBOSE yes i'd have to prefer DateTime classes for this, but this gets the job done

Comment: @sgtBOSE is it better to use `DateTime` for this kind of thing? Like John Conde's answer?

Comment: yes. `strtotime()` sometimes unable to distinguish formats properly. :)